# Swift Facebook SDK Logout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated the facebook sdk into my ios app but want to create a custom logout button as i think the uiview logout button the sdk provides does not fit my color scheme. does anyone know how I can run a method to do a facebook logout?

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
var theFBSession = FBSession.activeSession()
var check = FBSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation(theFBSession)
```

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Answer (score 12):

**Facebook SDK 4.X with Swift**

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager.logOut()
```

Answer (score 3):

For swift 3.0 add below code for **logout**

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late, but try this :

```
FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

**Logout from Facebook**

```
let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.logOut()
```

Answer (score 0):

Logout from Facebook Swift 5.0

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()
```

Comment: This does not logout any user.